# Border not curving with border-radius on Android 4+ and iOS 6.0

Tags: android, ios, css

I have a circle with a double border. The inner white border is set by the `border` property. The outer gray border is set by `box-shadow` property. On Android 4+ and iOS 6.0, the outer border is curving properly but the inner border is not.

Correct:

[image]

Incorrect:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
-moz-background-clip: padding;
background-clip: padding-box;

-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
border-radius: 50%;

-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #b2b0b0;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #b2b0b0;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #b2b0b0;

border: 3px solid white;
display: block;
height: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 100%;
```

Why would `border-radius` correctly effect `box-shadow` but not `border`?

Comment: The problem might be with the border-radius set with purcentage. Did you try with pixels values?

Comment: Using pixel values has the same result.

Comment: Wrapping the element in a div and giving applying the double border to that div fixed the problem.

Comment: Glad it's working now. You should post your solution and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I arrived at this workaround:

Wrap element in a div:

```
<div class="double-border">
  <img />
</div>
```

and apply the double-border to the wrapper:

```
.double-border {

   -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
   -moz-background-clip: padding;
   background-clip: padding-box;

   -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
   border-radius: 50%;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #b2b0b0;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #b2b0b0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #b2b0b0;

  border: 3px solid white;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I've found that this technique will not work for a single border applied using the `border` property. Instead, use a solid box-shadow as a substitute.